# When does Hopf bifurcation not occur?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider the system:
>   $$\begin{cases}
> \frac{dx}{dt}=\mu x + y \\
> \frac{dy}{dt}=-x+\mu y \\
> \end{cases},$$
>   where $\mu $ is a bifurcation parameter.
>   Explain why Hopf bifurcation does not occur?

The eigenvalues of the Jacobian matrix are: $\lambda=\mu \pm i.$ Hopf bifurcation occurs when the real part of the eigenvalue changes sign, which is when $\mu = 0$ in this case. Why then Hopf bifurcation cannot occur when we have a linear system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system changes globally from spiraling inwards for $μ<0$ to spiraling outwards for $μ>0$. There are no emerging limit cycles.

For a Hopf bifurcation to occur, you need that change locally around the fixed point while the global behavior far from the fixed point remains qualitatively unchanged. Only then do you get a ring-shaped region where the flow of the ODE is inwards along all of the boundary with no stationary points inside, which implies the existence of a limit cycle.